# How do I filter OUT a value from DataTables?

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

Instead of typing in a value in the Search box and only seeing data with that column value, I want to see all data that does not have that column value.

So, for example, if the column `Fry Size` had: `Small, Medium, Large, or Mega` as a possible value and I typed in `Mega` in the Search bar, I want to only see data that have: `Small, Medium, or Large` in the `Fry Size` column.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you could perform such custom search, but there're some pitfalls: datatables in general would nevertheless apply its own filtering before custom ones, so in your case adding custom filtering reflects in empty table. So, You could completely disable origin filtering mechanism by manipulating with `sDom`:

```
'sDom': '<"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">'
```

Add some input for your own filtering:

```
<input type="text" id="reverseSearch" />
```

Then apply custom filtering:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
       var frySize = data[1]; // from the fiddle example
       var searchPhrase = $("#reverseSearch").val();
       if (searchPhrase) {
            return !(frySize.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchPhrase.toLowerCase()) > -1);
       }
       return true;
    }
);
```

And, finally, bind this new serachbox to datatables `draw` event:

```
$('#reverseSearch').keyup(function () {
       table.draw();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChernikovP/sq9vfkr3/)